# Sonar Plugin Development - Create a global metric

Tags: java, sonarqube

I'm trying to create a custom sonar plugin that consists of a widget on the global dashboard.

I want this to display a "global" metric. So for example, a metric showing the number of lines across all projects.

Is this possible, if so how can I go about this? I can only find example projects that run project specific metrics. They output them in the ruby template like this: `format_measure('random')`. I am guessing this format measure only works in project context.

The documentation is **extremely** light on this whole process. So if anyone knows of any good documentation or guides that would also be useful, currently trying to piece together what I want to do from about 10 other plugins.

The only documentation I have found is here: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Developing+Plugins

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, there is no such concept as a global metric/measure in SonarQube. Aggregating metrics across projects is one of the features of the (commercial) [Portfolio Management](http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/governance/portfolio-management/) plugin.

If I were to develop such kind of plugin by myself, I would probably do the aggregation based on the result of a [Measure Filter](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Measures#Measures-Filters).

Comment: Thanks for the response, are you aware of a way to pass arbitrary values to the ruby widget templates? I can get the data I need directly from the database, I just need a way to pass that data to a widget template

Answer (score 1):

You can create global widgets by annotating them with the org.sonar.api.web.WidgetScope annotation, giving WidgetScope.GLOBAL as its argument:

```
import org.sonar.api.web.WidgetScope;

@WidgetScope(GLOBAL)
public class ExampleWidget extends AbstractRubyTemplate implements RubyRailsWidget {
  ...
```

Source: http://sonarqube.15.x6.nabble.com/sonar-dev-Global-dashboards-and-plugin-widgets-in-Sonar-3-1-td4999250.html

I do not know which ruby templating functions are available for global widgets.